# unable to capture 'g-recaptcha-response' for Recaptchav2 with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha

So I've been trying to build a webscraper but some of the data I need to scrape is locked behind a reCaptcha. From what I've gathered scouring around on the internet is every captcha has a TextArea element with the 'g-recaptcha-response' that gets filled in as the captcha is completed. The current solution for testing is to simply get around the captcha with me manually doing it and trying to capture the response and feed it back into the headless browser however I'm unable to get the response since as soon as the answer is submitted it can no longer find the response element.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='g-recaptcha-response']"}
```

```
    public static String captchaSolver(String captchaUrl) {
        setUp();
        driver.get(captchaUrl);
        new WebDriverWait(driver,2);
        try {
            while (true) {
                String response = driver.findElement(By.name("g-recaptcha-response")).getText();
                if (response.length()!=0) {
                    System.out.println(response);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Recaptcha mechanisms exists to stop robots like selenium. Even if you manage to capture responce once, the verification starts to loop and never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the element by CSS like this:

```
*[name*='g-recaptcha-response']
```